# sql query involving 3 tables

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 3 tables just like:-

```
    Table_1               Table_2                    Table_3
------------------------  --------------------  --------------------
id  bk_title  strm_id     bk_no   bk_isbn            s_id    strm_name
-----------------------  ---------------------  -----------------------
1   A_Book    3           1       ISBN0001           3       Science
2   B_Book    4           1       ISBN0002           4       History
                          2       ISBN0003
```

I want to fetch records as

```
BK_Title    Num_Copies  Stream
---------------------------------------
A_Book      2       Science
B_Book      1       History
```

How do i do so.Please advice.

Comment: This is a basic query that has two joins and a group by.

Comment: Thanks for the lead and down voting.However SELECT a.BK_TITLE,count(*) as num_copies,c.strm_name
from table_1 a
JOIN table_2 b On a.id = b.bk_no
JOIN table_3 c ON a.strm_id = c.strm_id
group by a.bk_title does not compile.

Comment: . . I don't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT BK_Title, COUNT(Table_2.bk_isbn) AS Num_Copies, Table_2.strm_name AS Stream
FROM Table_1
JOIN Table_2 on (Table_1.id = Table_2.bk_no)
JOIN Table_3 on (Table_1.strm_id = s_id)
GROUP BY BK_Title, strm_name
ORDER BY BK_Title
```

Comment: Thanks @AlxDroidDev for your answer.